# Grails java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated

Tags: tomcat, grails, illegalstateexception, jsessionid

We are getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated` error in low numbers in our grails application.

We tried checking if the session invalid in a filter and redirecting to the same page if yes but that didn't work. Looks like session gets invalidated in the middle of a request.

What is the proper way to handle this error? Should we put an error handler at top level and return some http status?

Answer (score 4):

We were also getting random `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated` exceptions in the middle of requests in our Grails 3.3.9 application.

We could hunt down the errors to these two causes:

**1) Expired sessions**. We fixed it by increasing the session timeout in `application.yml` to one workday.

```
server:
  session:
    timeout: 28800 # 8h in seconds ...
```

**2) 'User logout' caused by browser 'link preloading'**. Modern browsers will preload links in a page before the user tries to access them. This increases the loading speed when the user later clicks the link. This means if your 'logout link' is a simple link that accepts GET requests, the browser might log you out even if you don't want to.

We found that we hat a link to do the logout. So we changed it from GET to POST. Our logout link was as follows:

```
<g:link controller="logout">
    <g:message code="title.logout" default="logout" />
</g:link>
```

so we changed it to

```
<a href="#" onclick="document['hiddenLogoutForm'].submit();">
    <g:message code="title.logout" default="logout" />            
</a>
<form style="display: none"
      name="hiddenLogoutForm"
      method="POST"
      action="${createLink(controller:'logout') }" >
</form>
```

those two changes made the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated` disappear. Good luck!

Comment: The solution by Marc saved my skin. After a recent release of Chrome students that use my public facing 'learn-how-to-code' site experienced problems. The logfile started filling with 'Session already invalidated' exceptions. Marc's suggestions work for Grails 4.0.4.